# how to make the layout of horizontal barplot tight?

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I have this horizontal barplot that I want to plot, but the distance between the plot in y-axis is too huge. I want to make it tight. I tried it with *tight_layout*, but it doesn't work.
This is the horizontal barplot that I have:
[image]

and this is my attempt:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15))
f.tight_layout()
plt.barh(df['keywords'], df['number'], height=0.2)
ax.tick_params(labelsize=28)
plt.title('Difference average of cluster 4')
```

Comment: one option would be changing the total height of your plot: `f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,5))`

Comment: another is to change the `height` keyword (default is `0.8`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try enabling auto scaling by adding the following line.

```
plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='y', tight=True) # tight layout
```

Answer (score -2):

Mathplotlib uses auto fill x,y space in canvas. To make bars loot tight you need to set `heihgt = 0.9`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
data = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.5,0.3]
y_pos = [0,1,2,3,4]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,4))
ax.barh(y_pos, data, align='center', height=0.9)
ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
ax.set_yticklabels(labels)
plt.show()
```

[image]

or put some data above the rest to auto scale height of bars.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f')
data = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.5,0.3, 0.5]
y_pos = [0,1,2,3,4, 10]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,4))
ax.barh(y_pos, data, align='center', height=0.9)
ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
ax.set_yticklabels(labels)
plt.show()
```

[image]